# regex - Match filename with or without extension

Tags: regex, logstash-grok

Need a regex pattern to match all of the following:

```
hello
hello.
hello.cc
```

I tried `\b\w+\.?\w+?\b`, but this doesn't match `"hello."` (the second string mentioned above).

Comment: the problem is that you enforce the word boundary `\b` after the dot, which doesn't match. Try this instead: `\b\w+\.?(\w+\b)?` https://regex101.com/r/lX1aE0/1 For more explanations about word boundaries, check this http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Comment: @bro Actually, it's twofold, both the word boundary and the fact that he demands at least one char after the dot. Your solution solves both though, submit an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about as simple as I can get it:

```
\b\w+\.?\w*
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/vneq93Qnd5)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you enforce the word boundary `\b` after the dot, which doesn't match and the fact that you require at least one character after with `\w+?` (lazy matching!).
Try this instead:

```
\b\w+\.?(\w+\b)?
```

https://regex101.com/r/lX1aE0/1

For more explanations about word boundaries, check this link
http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Comment: The mistake in the regex is also that there's an enforced lazy "one or more" quantifier (`\w+?`) after the dot, which prevents the match.

Comment: @melwil. Yes thanks for your correction. I adapted my answer.

Comment: the second `\b` is redundant. `\w+` will consume everything up the the next word boundary. ie `\w+\b` === `\w+`